# php field required not working it procceeds the code

Tags: php

I have a form the creates pages using php

but here I am trying to make some of my form inputs required but it's not working

here's my whole php code

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
        echo 'File name is Required.';  
    } 
    // the name of the file to create 
    $filename=$_POST['filename']; 

    // the name of the file to be in page created 
    $strin=$_POST['strin']; 

    // the name of the file to be in page created 
    $strin2=$_POST['strin2']; 

    // the name of the folder to put $filename in 
    $thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder']; 

    // make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder 
    if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder)) { 
        // if not, we need to make a new folder 
        mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder); 
    } 
    // . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php 
    $myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php"; 

    // This is another way of writing an if statment 
    $div = ($strin !== '') ? 
    '<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>' 
    : '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>'; 

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
    $stringData = ""; 

    fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
    fclose($fh); 
} 
?>
```

this is what I tried, it says that field is required but it will proceed to run the code and do the job

```
if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
    echo 'File name is Required.';  
}
```

Comment: try to `return` after your check if you want to stop executing the rest of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add return keyword after your check like this:

```
if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
echo 'File name is Required.';  
return;
}
```

or add the rest of your code in `else` statement like this:

```
else {
$filename=$_POST['filename']; 
// the name of the file to be in page created 
$strin=$_POST['strin']; 
// the name of the file to be in page created 
$strin2=$_POST['strin2']; 
// the name of the folder to put $filename in 
$thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder']; 
// make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder 
if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder)) { 
// if not, we need to make a new folder 
mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder); 
} 
// . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php 
$myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php"; 

// This is another way of writing an if statment 
$div = ($strin !== '') ? 
'<div id="div1">'.$strin.'</div>' 
: '<div id="div2">'.$strin2.'</div>'; 



$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
$stringData = ""; 

fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
fclose($fh); 
} 
}
```

Comment: so return means start over and don' excute the rest of code am i right ?

Comment: any code after the return keyword will not be executed.

Comment: ok so how do i added multiple names here ? if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
echo 'File Name is Required.';
return; 
}

Comment: do you mean multiple fields?

Comment: you could add another if statement for your second field.

Comment: it's ok we are here to help each other.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
echo 'File name is Required.';  
return;
}
```

Return will break(exit) the current iteration

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: thanks a lot dear for your hard work but @amr answered to this first :)

Comment: Appreciate your feedback and amr response. You may choose to select the answer that you think that worked for you. We all are here to help, ranther than compete.

Comment: thanks or being so kind. if you can help me dear on chat i would really appreciate it because i need some help withing my code

Comment: What chat do wish me to help?

Comment: here you must be able to send me chat request

Comment: I guess that will only come after certain limit of comments.

Comment: oh ok then i will try ti ask you here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137191/discussion-between-smit-and-mm-pp).

Comment: you see my php code above . also i have a form i will add it at bottom of my question. i need to make first option of that select box as default. now if i run my code i have option called default but will run and make a folder with name of default. and i don't want to do that. i must keep option default as not selected anything so if i proceed it must tell me option if required